# CK editor not displaying on the bolt site

Tags: ckeditor, bolt-cms

My Bolt site does not display the ck editor. It just blinks and then disappears. The editor is supposed to show up under the html title. Here is how it looks. [image]

It seemed to work when I use the ethernet connection. The wifi is pretty good so I don't see any reason why that should affect it.

If anyone could help me out it would be great! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get any errors in console?

Comment: It finally worked! It just magically started working after a day or two!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the 404s… it looks like for some reason, potentially rewrites, the bolt.js file isn't being found.

Answer (score 0):

Please give out more details
check your server log and put it the outcome

this can help us to identify easily the issues

the easiest way is to use a PHP development server

you can do this by launch the `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t . index.php` in your root directory or if you have installed bolt with a special public directory you must run it down there